# Need help on Zookeeper events and Queues

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere, marathon, php-zookeeper

We have a backend module which listen ActiveMQ, after changing the backend arch, we are using Mesos,Marathon and Zookeeper,

Now we want to listen Zookeeper events, if any update come to zookeeper.

Is there any Client or anything, for connect to Zookeeper and listen the Zookeeper Queues/Events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are ZooKeeper bindings (client libraries) for a variety of languages, you can use those libraries to interact with ZooKeeper. The [ZooKeeper Programmer's Guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html) is a great place to start. And here is the link to [Curator](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/introducing-curator-netflix-zookeeper.html).

Answer (score 0):

We're using apache curator framework for this purpose. There is watch method which allow you to subscribe for specific path and listen for different events from it. Like: node created, updated, deleted or child changed...

Comment: I am not good at C++ and Java coding. any simple code that connect to Zookeeper using this Curator.